# installing eric5 in CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, python

I am trying to install Eric Python IDE 5 in my CentOS 6.4. The problem here is even I have installed PyQT4 its again saying that module is missing. what I am supposed to do ? here is the terminal log

```
[root@localhost eric5-5.3.5]# yum install PyQt4
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * epel: mirrors.vinahost.vn
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
Setting up Install Process
Package PyQt4-4.6.2-9.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@localhost eric5-5.3.5]# python3 install.py 
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.3.2
Sorry, please install PyQt4.
Error: No module named 'PyQt4'
[root@localhost eric5-5.3.5]#
```

how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Please add the output of: `python --version` Then add the [symbolic link from this tutorial](http://www.shayanderson.com/linux/install-python-3-on-centos-6-server.htm), as Bratchley and Gert have both noted.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `python3` interpreter but the PyQt4 you get from the repo's is for python 2.6:

```
[root@ditirlns02 cups]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
[root@ditirlns02 cups]# rpm -ql PyQt4
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/Qt.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtAssistant.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtDesigner.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtHelp.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/QtNetwork.so
[.....snip.....]
```

So that's basically why your install script isn't finding it: it's being installed for the wrong interpreter.

I might ask how you got python 3.0 on there, since it doesn't look like it's in the official repo's for RHEL/CentOS 6 either. If you found a third party repo, there may be a specific PyQt4 package for python 3.0 as well. Otherwise, you may have to try to build PyQt4 from source.

Comment: from source i have taken

Answer (score 0):

Your `PyQT4` module is installed on the default python (in this case python 2.6).

You can verify this by running:

```
$ python
>>> import PyQT4
```

I suggest you install PyQT4 from source (download and run `python3 setup.py install`).

Answer (score 0):

As Python version is 3.3.2, install `pip` first.

```
wget -O - 'https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py' | python3 -
```

Install SIP

download from 'http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download' and unpack.

```
cd sip-4.x.y && python3 configure.py && make && sudo make install
```

replace x.y with version.

Install PyQt4

Download from 'http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download' and unpack.

```
cd PyQt-x11-gpl-4.x.y && python3 configure-ng.py && make && sudo make install
```

replace x.y with version.

Check if it's working, `python3 -c 'from PyQt4 import QtCore' && echo ok || echo no`

Other python packages should be installed for non-system python and virtual environments (virtualenv and pyvenv) thru`pip`

```
python3 -m pip install 'package_name'
```

For system python (`/usr/bin/python`), always use `yum`. If used, `pip` might upgrade some python packages for dependency which might break `yum`.